# Counting executions for a precise Big(O)

Tags: java, big-o, coding-efficiency

I need help understanding how each line is calculated for a "precise" big o notation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
sum += i;
}
```

To my understanding this is the breakdown.

```
int i = 0;  --> 1
i < n;      --> n + 1
i++;        --> n
sum += i;   --> n (should I be thinking of this as a simple addition and assignment n times?)
JUMP to top --> n
```

thus, adding up to    **4n + 2**

Im unsure of how I'm approaching it, and it seems like there are many ways to do it. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I know this is silly because it defeats the purpose of Big Oh in the first place, but it is required for my class and my teacher has not been helpful in explaining how we are to calculate the executions line by line.

Comment: 4n + 2 is O(n). The significant point is just that your loop runs n times. If you doubled n, the loop would run twice as many times. That makes it O(n).

Comment: Refer to the definition of "big O" notation.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the notion of a "precise" big O?

Comment: The point of big-O is to be imprecise.

Comment: I understand that it acts as O(n), and that this is the whole point of Big oh. But for my class we have to come up with a "Presice" number and are graded on it. I know how to get the normal Big oh, and not the one that requires counting the executions.

Comment: @PrometheusAurelius Then you should ask your teacher what exactly you are supposed to count as an operation. There is no obvious answer to that. But I suspect that it isn't meant to be that precise. I would for example accept if you said that the number of instructions in the loop body is some constant, call it `c`, and the loop is executed `n` times, so the total number of instructions is `c*n`. Then add that the `int i = 0;` and the last `i < n` are another constant `d1` and `d2` giving a total of `c*n + d1 + d2`, which is `O(n)` without it mattering what `c` and `d1` and `d2` are.

Comment: I don't think you should ask a teacher or the "not a homework site." Your counting does not appear off.